# Will my mobile phone carrier charge me extra fares if my phone switched to a different carrier while I was using data roaming inside the EU?

Tags: eu, roaming

I am from Hungary and I am currently in France now. When I arrived here, my mobile phone carrier sent me an SMS that stated that the equivalent of my carrier I use in Hungary (Vodafone) is STR. I left the carrier selection on my phone on Automatic.

After a while, I noticed that the carrier my phone was using is not STR but Orange F. The problem is that I did not notice the change in time and actively used cellular data in the meantime.

Will this affect my monthly bill? Should I do anything about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your phone cannot simply connect to a random network. If you've used data on Orange France there exists an agreement between your Hungarian provider and Orange on mutual roaming, otherwise your phone would not be authorized to join their network. In addition, [the EU rules on roaming](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/faq/question-and-answers-roaming) make no exception for joining a different terrestrial network within a given country. The only exception is for non-terrestrial networks, such as those available on cruise ships:

> EU roaming rules apply only to terrestrial mobile networks. As soon as the services are provided through other types of radio networks, via satellite systems on board of ships or aeroplanes for instance, they are not subject to the binding price caps of the EU.